# How to know if the user input a registered valid email address that exists?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, email

I want to do is make a registration form with a email required but the user should input a valid registered email address. If the email is not valid, then the registration is not complete. How do I do that?

Example:

```
<form>
    <input type="email" name="email" required="required" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Send email with link to activate account, after registration - usual way we can see on many sites.

Comment: valid HOW? meets the RFC standard for an email address? Or an email address that actually exists and can be used? e.g. `postmaster@127.0.0.1` is a perfectly valid email address, but it's not exactly useful.

Comment: Keep in mind that you should do the check on server side if you wan't to be 100% sure. Otherwise someone just could fire up the Developer Tools and edit the JavaScript to always return true and/or remove the `required` attribute from the `<input>` tag.

Comment: Use a DB along with a verification code sent to their email associated with their email address and a unique token. Once clicked, they're entered as approved in DB; done deal.

Comment: Plus, make sure that if you're going to be using Emails for newsletter stuff etc, that it conforms to Anti-Spam laws which are now in effect.

Comment: I do it in stages - eliminate the most obvious errors first with an RFC compliant RegExp (either in JS or on the server), then check the MX record on the domain (getmxrr) and finally, if it looks OK so far, send an email with a verification link in... this enables you to quickly trap and report any (common) errors to the user as they're going rather than have them mail you asking why they never got their validation email straight away. Doesn't help, of course, if they do something like enter a valid domain that they're not signed up to (e.g. they entered .com instead of .co.uk).

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want the usual approval loop then your choice would be paying for the online service, like:

[Verify-Email.org](https://verify-email.org/)

They say:

**Looking to verify an email?**
This email verification tool actually connects to the mail server and checks whether the mailbox exists or not.

**What is being verified:**
Format: "name@domain.xxx"
Valid domain: "somebody@new.york" is not valid
Valid user: verify if the user and mailbox really exist

Disclaimer: I'm not in any way connected to them, advertising was not my intent.
There might be similar free services, but I would not trust those, since they are most likely harvesting email addresses. Free as cheese in the mousetrap.

Answer (score 0):

A common way developers use for verifying e-mail addresses is to have a `server-side` script send a randomly generated code that you associate with that address in the database (assuming you'll be storing the e-mail address).

Once the user receives the e-mail they can either enter the code in a form or click a link to verify the e-mail address. You would use a second `server-side` script to compare the code entered by the user and the one in the database and confirm that they match, thereby verifying the e-mail address.

Comment: It's already been said in comments; this doesn't add anything new or unique.

Comment: Unfortunately, comments are actually supposed to solicit for more information. They are not meant to answer the question. Here is what the placeholder says: **`Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments.`**

Answer (score -1):

I dont know how to check the email is valid and registered, but i use this quite often to check the email address entered at least follows the correct format.

```
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
    var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos< 1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length) {
        alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: There are lots of invalid email addresses that pass your function doesn't see as invalid. Also, this wasn't really the question.

Comment: that why i started by mentioning that this is not what he asked for, ill assume you just missed that bit, but its in the same faith, and just ensures the email address has the basics, i.e. an @ sign, and at least 1 dot after that sign. it was never meant to be the accepted answer but its just another idea as a starting point for something he/she has possibly not considered.